# How to Autoindent Ruby source code in Vim

Tags: ruby, vim, auto-indent

suppose I have `set cindent` in `.vimrc`

`def func()` followed by `Enter`, and then type `end`, it is indented(not aligned to the `def`) 

How to reindent the `end` keyword(align it to the `def`). 

 
Even using `endwise.vim plugin` doesn't fix the problem 
https://github.com/tpope/vim-endwise.git 
It adds **automatically** the `end` keyword but again `indented`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[vimfiles](https://github.com/scrooloose/vimfiles) includes ruby code smart indention and a lot of other useful things

ruby code is automatically formatted like

```
class Foo
  def bar
    if xxx
      blah
    else
      blahblah
    end
    barfoo
    barfoo
  end
end
```

Comment: What worked for me was installing `vim-pathogen` <br /> https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen.git

Answer (score 24):

Try using `smartindent` instead of `cindent` (which follows C-like indent behaviour), and turn on the filetype specific indent.

You'll also probably need to turn off vi compatibility.

Try adding this to you .vimrc:

```
" Turn off vi compatibility
set nocompatible

set smartindent
set autoindent

" load indent file for the current filetype
filetype indent on
```

Comment: I get indentation but it's wrong based on filetype? For ruby files I get huge tab indentation, while I'm supposed to get just 2 spaces ?

Comment: And to disable `set nosmartindent`, `set noautoindent`, `filetype indent off`

Answer (score 1):

In my case this is what fixed my indentation issues (e.g. jumps in random places):

```
set smartindent
set noautoindent
filetype indent off
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
" Ruby indentation from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=290462
if has ("autocmd")
    filetype indent on
endif
```